# find something good/ find something to be good

Tags: sentence-patterns

May I ask if there is any difference in connotation/ formality, when switching the sentence structure 'find something good' to 'find something to be good'? Sometimes my editors did this change in editing my articles. Below please see one example. Thanks!

**Original Version:**
He used the word ‘pu jie’ during a Legislative Council meeting, probably because he **found it coarse**.

**Revised Version:**
He used the word ‘pu jie’ during a Legislative Council meeting, probably because he **found it to be coarse**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thnk both are right depending on the context.
[image]